# Bootstrap static layout "visual" left right gutters firefox chrome

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently embarked on my own bootstrap project and keep running into a kind of a glitch. Using a static layout in Bootstrap I notice that different column layouts on different pages have different "overall" container widths. This causes the "visual" outermost gutters to "dance". Meaning a page with three small columns divs and a page with one small column div are going to have different container widths for each page. It tends to cause the navbar with it's links to contract and expand while navigating, with the left and right gutters "dancing" to the tune. I'm not sure I can find a workaround for this. On the other hand it only happens with Firefox and Chrome while Edge renders perfect gutters all the way. So maybe this really is being too picky, but is there a way of keeping the outer page gutters exactly the same across different pages using a static layout? As in using different layouts for different pages? On a browser like Firefox? Much appreciated.

Comment: I think I should add that this only happens when the page starts scrolling. Meaning I have a static page that needs to be scrolled. This is when the "gutters" or left and right margins change width along with the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with browsers and scrolling. Since when is software perfect anyway. My browser scrolling vote goes to Internet Explorer! Any case there's so many workarounds maybe there's no point in posting things this generic here? Also maybe Bootstrap is not perfect but it's pretty close? So handy! Thank you Twitter. Maybe I'll delete this thread sometime.